# mysqli query inside other mysqli query loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have made a CRM with imap webmail integrated in PHP.

And I am running some SQL queries on a MySQl database that take some time, and I bet there is a better way to do this, but I don't know how.

here is what I have:

I have all emails read from IMAP server indexed on a mysql database, so initially I do this query for example:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM emailaccount WHERE folder='Inbox' ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 50";
```

That query is normally fast, I get the results and show them.

But inside the loop for the 50 results I make another query to see if that email was anwsered for example. I do this:

```
if ($result=$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.$sql)){
        if( $result->num_rows > 0 ){
            while ($R = $result->fetch_array()){
              //do normal stuff
              $wasThisMailAnwsered = AnsweredMail($R["fromaddress"],$R["mailDate"]);
              //other normal things
            }
        }
}
function AnsweredMail($email,$date){

  global $mysqli;
  $email = addslashes($email);

  $pos1 = strpos($email,'<')+1;
  $pos2 = strpos($email,'>');
  $dif = $pos2 - $pos1;
  $mail = substr($email,$pos1,$dif);

  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM folder WHERE toAddress LIKE '%".$mail."%' AND date> '".$date."'");
  if($result->num_rows >= 1){
     return true;
  }
  else{
     return false;
  }

}
```

That is what I am doing, and of course when I call the second query inside function AnsweredMail() the initial query takes like 8 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this?

thank you in advance.

best,

Alvaro

UPDATE

Here is the database structure, the 2 queries are made to the same table, I first make a query to the table, and inside the loop other query to the same table.

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '.$usuarioCorreo.'   
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uid int,
  folder VARCHAR(200),
  date DATETIME,
  fromAddress VARCHAR(200),
  toAddress VARCHAR(200),
  cc VARCHAR(200),
  cco VARCHAR(200),
  subject VARCHAR(200),
  body TEXT,
  attachments VARCHAR(200),
  read VARCHAR(20),
  flagged VARCHAR(20),
  deleted VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)';
```

Comment: Could you possibly combine the 2 queries into a join ? Also, try selecting specific columns in place of `SELECT *` ? This could potentially make a difference based on the no. of columns in your table.

Comment: It is also possible that the additional processing in the function is what is taking time and maybe not the MySQL query itself.

Comment: Maximus, It looks like the additional processiong in the function is eating some time, but most of the time is consumed by the LIKE command, when I delete the additional processing in the function and change the like for " = " the query is fast. So I might change the database so I can have a table field with only the email (mail@domain) and not (name lastname <mail@domain>) that way I can query with " = " instead of " LIKE ". Besides that, do you think I should use JOIN ? I have never done that so I should google some JOIN tutorial.

Comment: That sounds like a better approach than what you are currently using. Can you also update your question with the structure of the two tables that you are using?

Comment: You might want to look at what fields are indexed in those tables. Proper indexing can speed up queries quite a bit.

Comment: With the JOINs you may not even need the function at all.

Comment: I just updated the table structure

Comment: Just realized that I can't JOIN the 2 queries, because it is the same table, just 1 table.

Comment: I ended up creating a field just for the email alone (mail@domain) so I can directly search with " = " instead of " LIKE ", and now the query is fast. But anyway, if there is a better way to do this I am listening, it seems that I can't make a JOIN because the 2 nested queries are for the same table.